# How do I add the username to the nav bar at the top of the web page?

Tags: python, django

After logging in, my Sign Up/Log In boxes should be removed, and replaced with a box consisting of the username that has logged in and linking to the user's profile.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Which bit exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <!-- display nav bar for the logged in user -->
{% else %}
    <!-- display login form or whatever you need -->
{% endif %}
```

with django you always have the authenticated user available in the request and this simple if/else statement helps with what you need. you can obviously make this an ajax call and call the html without the need of a new request

more info [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated)